# Thinkpad T14 enable wwan module Fibocom L860-GL

Tags: thinkpad, wwan

Have a new Thinkpad. T14 gen 1. With intel i5 processor. Laptop works very nice with Ubuntu.

Now I also installed a wwan module . The whitelisted Fibocom L860-GL. I am dual booting with windows and there the module is working. Had to do nothing special. Was plug and play

But in Ubuntu I can't get it to work. There is no wwan option in settings. And looking at the logs it seems Ubuntu does not detect it. I am running Ubuntu 20.10.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu maybe really can not detect it. Not sure what is going on exactly, but linux support is lacking for this device. Lenovo is working on it. So some good news might come someday. Still sad that it is hard in 2020 to buy hardware that has good Linux support. Even when a laptop is sold and listened as ready for linux/Ubuntu. A bit  disappointed.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Fedora-on-X1-Extreme-Gen-3-WWAN-Fibocom-L860-GL-4G-LTE-Advanced-Cat-16-not-working/m-p/5044699?page=1#5187313